# bpy Import FBX stuck loading

Tags: python, mesh, import

I have a script that batch processes fbx's for me, and I am having issues where specific meshes aren't importing when calling bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx() (27 of 73). The script will just stall on import on the weird pieces. The good pieces only take about 5-10 seconds to import, whereas I have left the pieces that aren't finishing for 30 minutes and they never got past that step. Is there any ideas of what may be the issue there?

I am using blender built as a python module in my script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Here is an example of a test for the crash.

```
import bpy

mesh_path = "my/path/here"

print("import started")
bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=mesh_path)
print("import finished")
```

Running that results in:

```
WARN (bgl): C:\blender-git\blender\source\blender\python\generic\bgl.c:2656 BPyInit_bgl: 'bgl' imported without an OpenGL backend. Please update your add-ons to use the 'gpu' module. In Blender 4.0 'bgl' will be removed.
importing started
FBX version: 7300
```

Then the process ends with no error or output after that. Whereas I can use normal Blender instead of my python module bpy, and it will import just fine.